# System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: The LDAP server is unavailable in DMZ server

Tags: c#, ldap, dmz

I'm using the below code, its working in my local. But its not working in DMZ server.

```
public string GetEmailByEmployeeId(string empID)
{
try
{
    using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
    {
        using (PrincipalContext adAuth = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, this.ADDomain))
        {
            UserPrincipal searchTemplate = new UserPrincipal(adAuth);
            searchTemplate.EmployeeId = empID;
            PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(searchTemplate);
            UserPrincipal user = (UserPrincipal)ps.FindOne();
            if (user != null)
            {
                return "Email: " + user.EmailAddress;
            }
            else
            {
                return "No Records Found";
            }
        };
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return e.ToString();
}
}
```

Getting below error: "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException: The server could not be contacted. ---> System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: The LDAP server is unavailable.

Comment: Code aside... can you connect from the server in the DMZ to LDAP?  To answer consider detail here:  https://serverfault.com/questions/363232/is-there-a-way-to-do-an-ldap-ping

Comment: I dont have telnet , is there any other way to test?

Comment: Assuming a windows environment you can try ldp.exe.  Reference:  http://www.computertechblog.com/using-ldp-exe-to-test-ldap-and-ldaps-connectivity/